# Updating objects/model across multiple controllers

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift2, updating

I'm a beginner working on swift. So in my project I have used multiple object/model, which I have used in almost all the controllers. My question is, how do I update my object/model(across all the controller)automatically when it is updated in any one of the controller?

What would be the correct way of performing this and how would I go about it??

Comment: you should add observers for your objects in controllers, and implement methods update your viewController UI

Comment: If the same model is used everywhere, why not have a singelton object of that model. This way no matter where you modify this the changes can ge obtained in all controllers. Do this only if you are sure of the requirement as this might cause untraceable bugs..

Comment: Can you just update some codes like how you're creating model , using your model object and updating model?

Answer (score 0):

There is concept of `Pass By Value & Pass By Reference`.

Best fit solution for your question is to use `Pass By Reference` type.

If we talk about `Swift programming language`.

`class` are Reference type & `struct` are Value type.

So, your model class should be build up with `class` type.

Code example.

```
class Dog {
    var breed : String = ""
    var sub_breed = [String]()
    init(_breed:String,_sub_breed:[String]) {
        self.breed = _breed
        self.sub_breed = _sub_breed
    }
}

FirstViewController:

var dogs : [Dog] = [Dog(_breed: “Original”, _sub_breed: [“subBreedType1”, “subBreedType2”])]

SecondViewController: // You are passing reference of dogs to SecondVC

var dogs : [Dog] = []

dogs[0].breed = “Modified”
```

Now you have changed value of `breed name` from `SecondViewController`, if you go back to `FirstViewController` and check the `first element` of array the value will be `“Modified”`

You can try this idea.

Other solutions : `Singleton object` of your `Model class`.

Thank you.